# Can't block connections to google via HOSTS file

Tags: hosts

Steam and Spotify connects to "clients.l.google.com" (172.217.21.206) using 5 to 100 kb. It might be analytics.

I blocked google.com, www.google.com, clients.l.google.com via hosts file, somehow it doesn't block it.

How would I get rid of it with or without hosts file?

Comment: the windows firewall lets you block specific programs from accessing the internet or perhaps accessing specific IPs, so maybe consider that as one possible solution.

Comment: No I can't do it via windows firewall

Comment: what do you mean you can't. It's not an option? It doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

There is a hosts file here, below that appears to completely block google.  If you just use the analytics and doubleclick sections you should retain usability.

```
#Begin code block

127.0.0.1 localhost

# ALWAYS make sure "127.0.0.1 localhost" is the first line in your /hosts file
# or your system or browser may malfunction!

# See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file to find the standard locations
# of the HOSTS file for your particular OS. In Linux (and probably BSD), it's
# usually under /etc/hosts

# Yes, I know there are some redundant entries in this block--you can grep it
# and remove them yourself if it really matters. I'm too lazy to do it myself.

# Redistribute and republish freely!

#first, let's redirect English google.com search to Startpage
216.218.239.164 google.com       #} redirects to us2.startpage.com:443
216.218.239.164 www.google.com   #} 216.218.239.164 is the IP address for the 
216.218.239.164 google.ca        #} Google frontend Startpage and automatically
216.218.239.164 www.google.ca    #} switches to https (443), even if http (80)
216.218.239.164 google.co.uk     #} is specified. SP is much more secure a
216.218.239.164 www.google.co.uk #} search engine and far more privacy-friendly
216.218.239.164 google.ie        #} than Google itself could ever hope to be.
216.218.239.164 www.google.ie    #}

#127.0.0.1 ajax.googleapis.com #commented out for compatibility with sites that
#127.0.0.1 apis.google.com     #dependencies on them some reason or other

#Youtube
127.0.0.1 youtube.com              #} you know the story
127.0.0.1 www.youtube.com          #}

127.0.0.1 i0.ytimg.com             #} mostly thumbnails, user pictures and
127.0.0.1 i1.ytimg.com             #} other unnecessary graphic clutter. Feel
127.0.0.1 i2.ytimg.com             #} free to leave blocked, as it also
127.0.0.1 i3.ytimg.com             #} improves YT's loading time considerably
127.0.0.1 i4.ytimg.com             #}
127.0.0.1 i5.ytimg.com             #}

127.0.0.1 s0.2mdn.net              #} comment out everything in this segment
127.0.0.1 static.2mdn.net          #} from this point down if you need to use
127.0.0.1 www.youtube-nocookie.com #} YT, since these next few servers are its
127.0.0.1 youtube-nocookie.com     #} dependencies and can cause major
127.0.0.1 youtube-noscript.com     #} functionality problems if blocked
127.0.0.1 www.youtube-noscript.com #}
127.0.0.1 s.ytimg.com              #} (s.ytimg.com is where the player is)

#various other G services - main pages
127.0.0.1 accounts.google.com #} comment out if you need to use G-mail
127.0.0.1 mail.google.com     #}
127.0.0.1 gmail.com           #}
127.0.0.1 www.gmail.com       #}
127.0.0.1 sites.google.com
127.0.0.1 code.google.com
127.0.0.1 maps.google.com
127.0.0.1 groups.google.com #} real Usenetters don't use Google Groups
127.0.0.1 gg.google.com     #}
127.0.0.1 plusone.google.com
127.0.0.1 fusion.google.com
127.0.0.1 plus.google.com
127.0.0.1 goog.le
127.0.0.1 youtu.be #youtu.be/AaBbCcDdEeFf is the same as youtube.com/watch?v=AaBbCcDdEeFf

#and here's where everything else originates. What a mess!
127.0.0.1 domains.googlesyndication.com
127.0.0.1 video-stats.video.google.com
127.0.0.1 4.afs.googleadservices.com
127.0.0.1 pagead2.googleadservices.com
127.0.0.1 partner.googleadservices.com
127.0.0.1 www.googleadservices.com
127.0.0.1 apps5.oingo.com
127.0.0.1 www.appliedsemantics.com
127.0.0.1 service.urchin.com
127.0.0.1 pagead2.googlesyndication.com
127.0.0.1 googlesyndication.com
127.0.0.1 ads.googlesyndication.com
127.0.0.1 www.googlesyndication.com
127.0.0.1 adwords.google.com
127.0.0.1 googleanalytics.com
127.0.0.1 ssl.googleanalytics.com
127.0.0.1 www.googleanalytics.com
127.0.0.1 google-analytics.com
127.0.0.1 .google-analytics.com
127.0.0.1 ssl.google-analytics.com
127.0.0.1 www.google-analytics.com
127.0.0.1 www.googletagservices.com
127.0.0.1 ssl.googletagservices.com
127.0.0.1 .googletagservices.com
127.0.0.1 googletagservices.com
127.0.0.1 www.gstatic.com
127.0.0.1 csi.gstatic.com
127.0.0.1 doubleclick.com
127.0.0.1 .doubleclick.com
127.0.0.1 gan.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 .doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad-g.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 googleads.g.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.ie.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 static.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 partner.googleadservices.com
127.0.0.1 ssl.gstatic.com
127.0.0.1 clients.google.com
127.0.0.1 clients1.google.com
127.0.0.1 clients2.google.com
127.0.0.1 clients3.google.com
127.0.0.1 clients4.google.com
127.0.0.1 clients5.google.com
127.0.0.1 clients6.google.com
127.0.0.1 clients7.google.com
127.0.0.1 clients8.google.com
127.0.0.1 clients9.google.com
127.0.0.1 clients0.google.com
127.0.0.1 sassets.vevo.com   #} some Youtube-related ad servers
127.0.0.1 2975c.v.fwmrm.net  #}
127.0.0.1 m.v.fwmrm.net      #}
127.0.0.1 .fwmrm.net         #}
127.0.0.1 ytimg.googleusercontent.com # needless Youtube-related graphic clutter
127.0.0.1 html5shiv.googlecode.com
127.0.0.1 b3.caspio.com
127.0.0.1 ajax.microsoft.com
127.0.0.1 buttons.googlesyndication.com
127.0.0.1 googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 lh0.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 lh1.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 lh2.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 lh3.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 lh4.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 lh5.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 lh6.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 lh7.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 lh8.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 lh9.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 s.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 s0.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 s1.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 s2.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 s3.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 s4.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 s5.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 s6.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 s7.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 s8.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 s9.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 chrome.google.com
127.0.0.1 fonts.googleapis.com
127.0.0.1 checkout.google.com
127.0.0.1 .ggpht.com
127.0.0.1 lh1.ggpht.com
127.0.0.1 lh2.ggpht.com
127.0.0.1 lh3.ggpht.com
127.0.0.1 lh4.ggpht.com
127.0.0.1 lh5.ggpht.com
127.0.0.1 lh6.ggpht.com
127.0.0.1 fonts.googleapis.com
127.0.0.1 gp1.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 gp2.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 gp3.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 gp4.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 gp5.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 gp6.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 gp7.googleusercontent.com
127.0.0.1 chart.apis.google.com

#crap from Doubleclick - mostly ad/spyware servers
127.0.0.1 conversion-pixel.invitemedia.com
127.0.0.1 analytics-api-samples.googlecode.com
127.0.0.1 m1.2mdn.net
127.0.0.1 rmcdn.2mdn.net
127.0.0.1 rmcdn.f.2mdn.net
127.0.0.1 n339.asp-cc.com
127.0.0.1 ads.cc-dt.com
127.0.0.1 clickserve.cc-dt.com
127.0.0.1 creative.cc-dt.com
127.0.0.1 clickserve.dartsearch.net
127.0.0.1 clickserve.eu.dartsearch.net
127.0.0.1 clickserve.uk.dartsearch.net
127.0.0.1 doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad-g.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad2.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.ae.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.ar.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.at.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.au.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.be.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.br.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.ca.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.ch.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.cl.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.cn.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.de.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.dk.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.es.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.fi.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.fr.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.gr.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.hk.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.hr.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.hu.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.ie.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.in.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.jp.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.kr.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.it.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.nl.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.no.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.nz.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.pl.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.pt.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.ro.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.ru.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.se.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.sg.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.si.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.terra.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.th.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.tw.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.uk.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.us.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.za.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.n2434.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad-emea.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 creatives.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 dfp.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 feedads.g.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 fls.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 fls.uk.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 googleads.g.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ir.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 iv.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 m.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 motifcdn.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 motifcdn2.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 n4052ad.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 n4403ad.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 n479ad.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 paypalssl.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 pubads.g.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 s2.video.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 survey.g.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 anon.doubleclick.speedera.net #not sure if this is an actual DC server or not, but here it is
127.0.0.1 doubleclick.ne.jp
127.0.0.1 www3.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 www.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 doubleclick.com
127.0.0.1 www2.doubleclick.com
127.0.0.1 www3.doubleclick.com
127.0.0.1 www.doubleclick.com
127.0.0.1 tpc.googlesyndication.com
127.0.0.1 ad.rs.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 affiliate.2mdn.net
127.0.0.1 clickserve.us2.dartsearch.net
127.0.0.1 ad-apac.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.mo.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 adclick.g.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 gan.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 googleads2.g.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 n4061ad.hk.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 securepubads.g.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 ad.bg.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 cm.g.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 stats.g.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 fls.au.doubleclick.net
127.0.0.1 log2.quintelligence.com
127.0.0.1 www.destinationurl.com
127.0.0.1 doubleclick.shockwave.com
127.0.0.1 www3.webhostingtalk.com
127.0.0.1 ad.mirror.co.uk
127.0.0.1 host3.adhese.be
127.0.0.1 mcmads.mediacapital.pt
#End code block
```

Source: http://forums.radioreference.com/computer/269946-block-google-f-book-crap-using-your-hosts-file.html

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...

Comment: I've edited the answer and inserted the contents of the HOSTS file from the target link

Comment: you Sir are a Hero. for the Ages!

Comment: If your chrome extensions fail to download from chrome store you will need to comment out blocking "clients2.google.com" - some people have been having that issue